# Something eats my sweet potato leaves

Tags: leaves, pest-damage, sweet-potato

Something eats leaves, mostly youg ones, any idea what's that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I can't identify any pests when looking closer.

Comment: Sorry, I cant identify any, never having grown sweet potatoes.  However, my feeling is that there will be some bugs, unless you want to slather the plant with chemicals.  As long as the plant is still winning, it is okay.

Comment: I've been suspecting some bugs, but I can't see any.  Never had it before